# C: Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type error

Tags: c, reference, struct

The project I am trying to compile on OS X is: https://github.com/Ramblurr/PietCreator

Am unfortunately unable to fix the problems with the following lines:

```
width = info_ptr->width;
height = info_ptr->height;
ncol = 2 << (info_ptr->bit_depth - 1);
```

Which produce the errors:

```
file.c: In function ‘read_png’:
file.c:1117: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
file.c:1118: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
file.c:1119: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

Full code of the read_png function below:

```
#include <png.h>
#include <math.h>

png_byte bit_depth;

png_structp png_ptr;
png_infop info_ptr;
int number_of_passes;
png_bytep * row_pointers;


int
read_png (char *fname)
{
  char header [8];

  FILE *in;
  int i, j, ncol, rc;

  if (! strcmp (fname, "-")) {
    /* read from stdin: */
    vprintf ("info: not trying to read png from stdin\n");
    return -1;
  }

  if (! (in = fopen (fname, "rb"))) { 
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot open `%s'; reason: %s\n", fname,
         strerror (errno));
    return -1;
  }

  if (! in || (rc = fread (header, 1, 8, in)) != 8
      || png_sig_cmp ((unsigned char *) header, 0, 8) != 0) {
    return -1;
  }

  if (! (png_ptr = png_create_read_struct (PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, 0, 0, 0))
      || ! (info_ptr = png_create_info_struct (png_ptr))) {
    return -1;
  }

  png_init_io (png_ptr, in);
  png_set_sig_bytes (png_ptr, 8);

  png_read_png (png_ptr, info_ptr, 
        PNG_TRANSFORM_STRIP_16 | PNG_TRANSFORM_STRIP_ALPHA
        | PNG_TRANSFORM_EXPAND, NULL);
  /**       | PNG_TRANSFORM_PACKING | PNG_TRANSFORM_SHIFT **/

  row_pointers = png_get_rows (png_ptr, info_ptr);

  width = info_ptr->width;
  height = info_ptr->height;
  ncol = 2 << (info_ptr->bit_depth - 1);

  vprintf ("info: got %d x %d pixel with %d cols\n", width, height, ncol);

  alloc_cells (width, height);

  for (j = 0; j < height; j++) {
    png_byte *row = row_pointers [j];
    for (i = 0; i < width; i++) {

      png_byte *ptr = & row [i * 3];

      /* ncol always 256 ? */
      int r = (ptr [0] * 256) / ncol;
      int g = (ptr [1] * 256) / ncol;
      int b = (ptr [2] * 256) / ncol;

      int col = ((r * 256 + g) * 256) + b;
      int col_idx = get_color_idx (col);

      if (col_idx < 0) {
    if (unknown_color == -1) {
      fprintf (stderr, "cannot read from `%s'; reason: invalid color found\n",
           fname);
      return -1;
    } else {
      /* set to black or white: */
      col_idx = (unknown_color == 0 ? c_black : c_white);
    }
      }

      set_cell (i, j, col_idx);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Binary incompatibility exists only when applications make direct access to the info_ptr or png_ptr members through png.h, and the compiled application is loaded with a different version of the library" - this from my png.h. libpng 1.2.42 . Which version are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled the project on Mac OS X 10.6.8 successfully.

```
git clone https://github.com/Ramblurr/PietCreator.git   
cd PietCreator
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../

-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - not found.
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found.
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found.
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - found
-- Looking for QT_MAC_USE_COCOA
-- Looking for QT_MAC_USE_COCOA - found
-- Found Qt-Version 4.7.4 (using /usr/local/bin/qmake)
-- Looking for gdImagePng in /usr/local/lib/libgd.dylib
-- Looking for gdImagePng in /usr/local/lib/libgd.dylib - found
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/include (found version "1.2.3")
-- Found PNG: /usr/X11R6/lib/libpng.dylib 
-- Looking for gdImageJpeg in /usr/local/lib/libgd.dylib
-- Looking for gdImageJpeg in /usr/local/lib/libgd.dylib - found
-- Found JPEG: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.dylib 
-- Looking for gdImageGif in /usr/local/lib/libgd.dylib
-- Looking for gdImageGif in /usr/local/lib/libgd.dylib - found
-- Found GD: /usr/local/lib/libgd.dylib
-- Found GIF: /usr/local/lib/libgif.dylib 
-- Looking for include files HAVE_GD_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_GD_H - found
-- Looking for include files HAVE_PNG_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_PNG_H - not found.
-- Looking for include files HAVE_GIF_LIB_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_GIF_LIB_H - found
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Developer/workspace/png/PietCreator/build
```

After running `make` the application was compiled successfully:

```
Linking CXX executable pietcreator
[ 95%] Built target pietcreator
[ 97%] Generating NPietTest.moc
Scanning dependencies of target npiettest
[100%] Building CXX object npiet/CMakeFiles/npiettest.dir/test/NPietTest.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable npiettest
[100%] Built target npiettest
```

The only problems I ran into were all related to missing dependencies when executing `cmake ../`. I had to download/compile/install **Qt 4.7.4** and **Qt-mobility 1.2.0**. After that, I also needed **libgd** and **giflib** but then I used [**brew**](https://brew.sh/) for the job.

I suggest you try another `git clone` and try to compile it again from scratch.

If you would like to know, *brew* installed **gd 2.0.36RC1** and **giflib 4.1.6**.

Comment: Would you actually perhaps be able to send me the compiled files? I shall try recompiling myself and match the build numbers of the dependencies you used.

Comment: I might, but keep in mind that this may not work as you are expecting. Drop me a message on twitter with your email addr.

Comment: Turns out I had an outdated libjpeg library on my system that was causing other dependency issues. Running your compiled app showed me this and when updated, worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is by design of the creator of `png.h` module.

It should be that `png_infop` is declared as a **pointer to a struct** in `"png.h"`. The actual struct declaration and definition should be in `"png.c"`.

The author does not want to expose the internals of the `struct` so the `struct` is defined in the `"png.c"`.

This means you cannot access any member of the struct (i.e: `info_ptr->width`, `info_ptr->height`, `info_ptr->bit_depth`.

The `struct` members are not meant to be accessed by user.

I bet there are functions to access those members if the author thinks that you will need the `width`, `height`, or `bit_depth` information (i.e: `getWidth(info_ptr)`, `getHeight(info_ptr)`, ...).

Comment: I shall look into the source files more to see if this is the case. I have also edited my question to include the Github repo that I am trying to compile.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look in `png.h` (or its documentation), find out what the type `png_infop` is a pointer to, and then find out how you're supposed to access its fields. Assuming that this pointer is really the right thing to get that data from, then either you need to include the definition of that type (so that the compiler knows about its data members `width` etc) from some other header, or else there are getter functions you're supposed to call that take a `png_infop` parameter and return the info you're after.

[Edit: looks as if you're supposed to use `png_get_IHDR`, or `png_get_image_width` etc.]

Answer (score 0):

You usually get this error when you have a forward declaration in the header and you don't include the file for the corresponding class in the source file:

```
//header.h
class B;
class A{
A();
B* b;
}

//source.cpp
#include "header.h"
//include "B.h" //include header where B is defined to prevent error
A::A()
{
   b->foo(); //error, B is only a forward declaration
}
```

Therefore, you need to include the appropriate header, a forward declaration is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

incomplete reference  errors typically occur  when you have a construct as under:

```
struct foo;

int bar(void) {
     struct foo *p;
     p->a = 0;
}
```

here  The foo  struct  is declared however its actual content is not known,  And will yield  a dereferencing to an incomplete type error.

The philosophy behind this is to force a formal API usage to manipulate data structures. this ensures that future API can change the structure much more easily without affecting legacy programs.

So typically an API header will do something like this:

```
/*
 * foo.h part of foo API 
 */

struct foo;

extern void foo_set_a(struct foo *p, int value);
extern int foo_get_a(struct foo *p);
```

It will internally implement the foo API functions ... for instance:

```
/* 
 * foo.c ... implements foo API 
 */

struct foo {
   int a;
};

void foo_set_a(struct foo *p, int value) {
    p->a = value;
}

int foo_get_a(struct foo *p) {
    return p->a;
}
```

and then the user of foo API can:

```
use_foo() {
    struct foo *my_foo;
    foo_set_a(my_foo, 1);
}
```